# THREE AnimationMixer.clipAction() throws cannot parse trackname at all

Tags: animation, three.js

I am trying to load some simple keyframe animation (just positions) using the JSON loader.

Using the dev branch r80.

To load the entire scene (made and animated in softimage, exported to FBX, imported into blender, exported using the THREE JSON export script). The file looks good and loads ok.

But when i try to load the animation using:

```
object.traverse( function ( child ) {
    switch(child.name) {
        case "dae_scene:helium_balloon_model:helium_balloon_model":
                                //do anim
                                console.log(object.animations[0]);
                                animationClips.balloon1 = object.animations[0]; //
                                //animationClips.balloon1.weight = 1;

                                animationMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( child );

                                var sceneAnimation = animationMixer.clipAction(animationClips.balloon1);
                                    sceneAnimation.play();
        break;
    }
}
```

it produces:

three.min.js?ver=4.5.4:712 Uncaught Error: cannot parse trackName at all: dae_scene:helium_balloon_model:helium_balloon_model.position

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?